Writing $\tan t$ in terms of $\cos t,$ where $t$ is in Quadrant 3

Write $\tan t$ in terms of $\cos t,$ where $t$ is in Quadrant 3.

We start with the identity
$1 + \tan^2t = \sec^2t$:
$$\sec t = \frac1{\cos t}$$
$$\implies\tan^2t = \frac1{\cos^2t}- 1$$
$$\implies\tan^2t=\frac{1-\cos^2t}{\cos^2t}$$
$$\implies\tan t=\pm\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos^2t}}{\cos t}$$
Now, as $t$ is in Quadrant 3, tan t is positive, so
$\therefore\tan t=\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos^2t}}{\cos t}$ $\leftarrow$$1^{st}$ solution
Now, solving with a different identity
$\sin^2t + \cos^2t = 1$:
$$\implies\sin^2t = 1 - \cos^2t$$
$$\implies|\sin t| = \sqrt{1 - \cos^2t}$$
Since we're in Quadrant III, $\sin t$ is negative, so:
$$\sin t = -\sqrt{1 - \cos^2t}$$
$$\because \tan t = \frac{\sin t}{\cos t}$$
$\tan t=-\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos^2t}}{\cos t}$ ** $\leftarrow$ $2^{nd}$ solution**
Why is there a discrepancy in the signs of the first and the second solutions?

Welcome to Math SE. You state that $\sin t$ is negative in Quadrant III, but consider whether $\cos t$ is positive or negative in Quadrant III.

$~\displaystyle \sin(t) = \pm \sqrt{1 - \cos^2(t)},~$ depending on whether or not $~\sin(t) \geq 0.~$  In the 3rd quadrant, $~\sin(t) < 0.$


Now, as $t$ is in Quadrant 3, $\tan t$ is positive

True! But $\cos t$ is negative, and therefore
$$ \frac{\sqrt{1-\cos^2t}}{\cos t} < 0. $$
Therefore, because $\tan t$ is positive,
$\tan t \neq \frac{\sqrt{1-\cos^2t}}{\cos t}.$
The $+$ sign in $\pm$ is therefore ruled out.
On the other hand, for $t$ in Quadrant 3,
$$ -\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos^2t}}{\cos t} > 0. $$
Is it clear how to complete the first attempted solution correctly now?

Do you mean this?
In Quadrant III, $\tan t$ is positive, and $\cos t$ is negative, so you need to take the negative root for the numerator to ensure the final result is positive:
$$\tan t = \frac{-\sqrt{1-\cos^2 t}}{\cos t}$$

Yes, that's the idea. I used the formula as shown in the question, $\tan t=\pm\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos^2t}}{\cos t}$, but indeed choosing the sign of $\pm$ in that formula is the same as choosing the positive or negative square root of $1-\cos^2t$.


$\tan^2t = (1 - \cos^2t ) / \cos^2t $
$\tan t = \sqrt{1 - \cos^2t} / \cos t$

Notice that $\tan t$ and $\cos t$ might have opposite signs in the first line above, but not in the second line above. So, this step is invalid.
Your correction will need to consider the signs of $\tan$ and $\cos$ in Quadrant 3.
